# Stripe API recurring payments with Php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe API for one time payments, which works perfectly fine using something like:

```
  $stripe = array("secret_key" => "MY_SECRET_KEY", "publishable_key" => "MY_PUBLISHABLE_KEY");
  Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']); 

  try {
      $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
          "amount" => round($_POST['amount'] * 100, 0),
          "currency" => "USD",
          "card" => array(
              "number" => 111111111111111111,
              "exp_month" => 10,
              "exp_year" => 2017,
              "cvc" => 321,
              ),
          "description" => $_POST['item_name']));
      $json = json_decode($charge);
      $amount_charged = round(($json->{'amount'} / 100), 2);
      //process payment here......

  }
  catch (Stripe_CardError $e) {
      $body = $e->getJsonBody();
      print json_encode($json);
  }
```

Now I want to be able to have recurring payments, by capturing user credit card info, and running cron job once a month. Will the above work fine, or do I need something else. I'm aware that Stripe has built in feature for recurring payments, but in my case payments for each month will have different amount.

Comment: You should really **NOT** save the user's credit card info in your database. You can [change the amount of a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/guide#changing-the-amount-billed) using Strip's API.

Comment: storing the CC data on your end makes you subject to PCI compliance, and that's not something you want to get involved with. let stripe handle the storage.

Comment: All this is covered very well in their docs...

Answer (score 2):

The thing you're missing in your example is Customer records.  You see, Stripe doesn't allow you to re-use a Token.  They're one-time use.  In order to build out the functionality you're looking for, you'd need to securely store the payment details somewhere.  If you're PCI Compliant, that could, of course, be on your own local datastore; however, if you want to make it easy on yourself, you could build out Customer records for each user and their associated payment methods.

When you're constructing a charge normally, you'll use the [Create a Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) API Request.

You're doing this now and passing the token id as the `source`-argument.  What you would do instead, is first make a [Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer) and then attach that payment source by [creating a Card](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card).  (I recommend doing them as two separate steps, so you can better manage customers with multiple payment sources.)

Then, to charge that record again, you would make your [Create a Charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) API Request again, but instead you would pass in the customer id in the `customer`-argument and (optionally) pass in the source id (`card_xxx`) into the `source`-argument.  If you don't pass in a `source`-argument, but you pass a `customer`-argument, it will use the *default* payment source.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. Just to confirm. I don't need to capture token, only customer ID, and reuse the same customer ID for all the future charges. The steps are 1. Create Customer, 2. Create Card and 3. Create Charge.

Comment: Correct.  :)  Assuming there's a 1:1 relationship between Customers and Cards, you can even forego doing steps 1 and 2 independently, and simply pass the token id in for the `source`-argument when creating the customer record (https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just run a charge using the card token every month? Instead of passing in the card using their card token would be more secure. But otherwise your code looks fine. You should just be able to run a charge like that every month.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention that you will need to create a Stripe Customer and assign the CC token to that Stripe Customer since CC tokens are one time use only. After creating the Stripe Customer you will be able to just charge that customer every month.

Comment: Can I reuse the same token each month? I prefer that instead of CC info

Comment: You would have to create a Stripe customer with that CC token. Then charge that Stripe customer.

Comment: Setting the source of the customer to equal that CC token you get. Then you can just charge the customer. That example they give in the link above is very detailed in terms of comments of what to save and how to handle it.

Comment: You cannot re-use Stripe Card Tokens.  :(

Comment: @andrewnelder Forgot to make that clear in my answer. Need to create a customer first and charge that customer. Will edit now.